# How should this query be written?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically what I want to do is have a query where I have a table with Articles.
It's a simple table with Title, body, PublishedDate and AuthorID. 
Now what I want the query to do is. Sort the Articles by the PublishedDate and get the latest article for the author there this.

I also want to add the functionalty where for example I want to display the lastest two articles for each author. BUT  first it needs to take in consideration the published date not how many authors I want to display.

```
SELECT
  article_page.AuthorId,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(article_page.ID ORDER BY article_page.PublishedDate DESC
                  ), ',', 3) AS latest_articles
FROM ArticlePage AS article_page
GROUP BY article_page.AuthorId
LIMIT 2;
```

The following query is what i manged to do so far but thing is if it limit it to two Authors but the last author has the latest published date it doesn't show.

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the tables, a sample data set and the result that you are expecting from the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need an `order by`:

```
SELECT ap.AuthorId,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ap.ID ORDER BY ap.PublishedDate DESC
                                   ), ',', 3) AS latest_articles
FROM ArticlePage ap
GROUP BY ap.AuthorId
ORDER BY MAX(ap.PublishedDate) DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Note the use of table aliases.  These make a query easier to write and to read.